# Name of webcomic with no dialogue, set in a flat world inside an armillary sphere?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I'm looking for a recent webcomic that I read a few years ago but now cannot remember the name for. A complicating factor is that the comic had no text or dialogue as I remember it, so there really aren't any names for persons, things, places etc. Also, since things are never explained, some of the details I bring up below are just my interpretations of what really happened. Here are the things I can recall about it (some more certain than others):

- The creator is a storyboard artist, which is the reason why the comic has no text. It is more of a serialized storyboard project. The story is only implied through the art. The art is very professional, with a very clean, inked and coloured look.
- The comic was published on the creator's website and on [Artstation](https://www.artstation.com). It started on one but then switched to the other, though I can't recall which one it started on. The comic is finished, and ended quite recently, just a few years ago (max 5).
- The main characters are a young man from a backwater island and a defective robot soldier from an oppressive state/religion. Later they are joined by a young woman with tattoos that first try to kill them but is injured.
- In the beginning of the story, the young man's village is attacked, and he has to flee to avoid getting captured. The attackers are robot soldiers from the oppressive state. I think this is how he and the friendly robot soldier get together. Maybe the robot soldier was injured in the attack?
- There is a major plot point about a sword hilt with no blade that the robot soldier is carrying. We later learn it is a cult item for the oppressive state.
- The group travels on a quest through the world, which is mostly an archipelago. Early in the comic we see that the moon is moving on a track in the sky, and we later learn that the world is a flat disc inside a sphere where the moon's tracks are set. This is why I describe it as being inside an armillary sphere, although that is only partly correct.
- The group makes it to a huge city on an island that hangs on the very edge of the world disc there the oppressive state/religion is strong. They infiltrate the city and after going through some underground parts they make it to the temple at the top. The temple has a bridge into the air where the moon docks once per lap around the world.
- The heroes sneak and fight their way across the bridge when the moon is docked, and make their way into the inside of the moon. There they have more adventures and we learn of the connection between the temple, the moon rulers and the young woman. The moon moves beneath the world disc, through waterfalls.

If I could copy the images I have of this from my brain and into Google, I would find this in a heartbeat, but unfortunately(?) that doesn't work! Hope someone here can help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read it myself, but it sounds like you're talking about Tellurion by Matt Rhodes.

Link: https://tellurion.ca/pages/tellurion

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Thank you!